# Printing HTML Documents in UWP App using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core

Tags: c#, printing, uwp, webview2

I'm encountering a problem while trying to print an HTML document in my UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app using the Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core package. When I click on the print button, an exception is thrown with the message "Value does not fall within the expected range." Following this exception, the print dialog opens with an empty page. I'm struggling to identify the root cause of this issue.

Here's my relevant code :

```
        private async void PrintCallback()
        {
            try
            {
                _printHelper = new PrintHelper(_printCanvas);
                await _webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
                _webView.CoreWebView2Initialized += WebView2OnCoreWebViewInitialized;
                _webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_InitializationCompletedForPrinting;
                _webView.NavigateToString(_htmlString);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exception (log or display error)
                Debug.WriteLine($"PrintCallback Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }

        }
        private void WebView_InitializationCompletedForPrinting(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _printHelper.AddFrameworkElementToPrint(_webView);
            _printHelper.OnPrintFailed += ReleasePrintHelper;
            _printHelper.OnPrintSucceeded += ReleasePrintHelper;
            _printHelper.OnPrintCanceled += ReleasePrintHelper;
            _printHelper.ShowPrintUIAsync("Print");
        }
```

The _htmlString variable contains the correct HTML content. I would appreciate any insights or guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Thank you!

Comment: I think that error comes from your printer driver's UI

Comment: thanks for replaying ,but I'm inclined to disagree. It seems to be working well with images; however,the issue specifically when dealing with HTML documents